# Is there away to stream music from iPad to chromecast via AirPlay?

Tags: ipad, airplay, chromecast

Obviously there is not native support for that. But I wonder if there are any hacks to do that. Or if there are not solutions yet is it technically possible, does apple and google expose API which could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no such possibility to close that gap. I have read about an app to stream your local media from an iOS device (AirCast). It was an early beta and no longer available. Besides Google tries to prohibit such functionality to avoid bringing illegal media to TVs via their devices.

Comment: I don't know whether Google trying to prevent streaming local files was true at some point, but it doesn't appear to be now. Check out [Videostream](http://getvideostream.com/) with (very well executed) apps for both [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/videostream-for-google-ch/cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.videostream.Mobile) distributed through Google's official channels.